# How can I use async/await in 'new Promise' block to fetch data from an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, axios

I'm unable to use async/await inside a 'new Promise' block which throws `await is only valid in async function` error. I don't know if it's even possible but I need to use it or a way to achieve what I want. Here's what I'm trying to do:

A user types in a query and it goes through a `recursive function` called `doesExist`. I have to use a recursive function because the API doesn't always provide data for a query. The recursive function will try 3 times, that is, it will send 3 api requests for the data before returning an error saying 'data couldn't be fetched'. In the function, I return a new promise as I have to make api requests from there.

To fetch data, I used `request` before but I want to use `axios` now with async/await. So how can I use axios with async/await inside a `new Promise` block?

This is the code with `request`:

```
router.get('/example', async (req, res) => {

        try{
            const query = 'Superman';
            const data  = await doesExist(query);
    
            if(!data) {
                console.log('No data');
            }
    
            res.render('../views/example', { data, query });
        }catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        
});
    
    
const doesExist = (query, retries = 0) => {

        const url           = `http://api.example.com/json?fields=${query}`;
        const maxRetries    = 3;
    
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            
            const retry = () => {
                if (retries < maxRetries) {
                    resolve(doesExist(query, retries + 1));
                } else {
                    reject(`Could not get the data after ${retries} retries.`);
                }
            };
    
            request(url, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    const data = JSON.parse(body);
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    retry();
                }
            });
       });
};
```

And this is what I tried with `async/await` which throws the error:

```
const doesExist = async (query, retries = 0) => {

        const url           = `http://api.example.com/json?fields=${query}`;
        const maxRetries    = 3;
    
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            
            const retry = () => {
                if (retries < maxRetries) {
                    resolve(doesExist(query, retries + 1));
                } else {
                    reject(`Could not get the data after ${retries} retries.`);
                }
            };

            const data = await axios.get(url);

            if(data.statusCode === 200) {
                resolve(data);
            }else{
                retry();
            }
     
       });
};
```

If it's not possible to use async/await inside promise block then please show me how I can achieve it. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `new Promise(async ( resolve, reject ) => {`?

Comment: @Anatoly No, I just did. And it seemed to be working. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! If you want to use `async`/`await` and axios which already does return a promise, you don't need - and shouldn't use - the `Promise` constructor to [promisify a callback API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). Just write

```
async function doesExist(query, retries = 0) {
    const url           = `http://api.example.com/json?fields=${query}`;
    const maxRetries    = 3;

    const data = await axios.get(url);

    if (data.statusCode === 200) {
       return data;
    } else if (retries < maxRetries) {
       return doesExist(query, retries + 1);
    } else {
       throw new Error(`Could not get the data after ${retries} retries.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I had another question. Suppose I have to do more error handling inside that doesExist function beside that throw new Error you used. Should I do that inside this function or I'll just leave it for the try/catch block in the endpoint to do it?

Comment: @Zak Depends on whether those errors would be handled by retrying (incrementing the `retries` count) or not

Comment: No. Say I have to make another api call to a different endpoint in the first if block instead of ```return data```. Now the errors of this new call should be handled in the try/catch block in ```router.get``` section?

Comment: There's no general principle. Can those errors be handled by `doesExist`, still returning a reasonable result to the caller? Then you'd handled them inside `doesExist`. If you can't handle them, throw exceptions (i.e. reject the returned promise).

Comment: @BryanGrace If you refer to my first sentence, that's actually universal. Really no exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

The function the promise calls needs to be an "async" function like so.

```
new Promise (async (Resolve) => {
    await new Promise (async (_Resolve) => {
         console.log ("A");
         _Resolve ();
    });

    console.log ("B");
    Resolve ();
});
```

Comment: Promise inside a promise? I don't understand.

Comment: axios.get(url); returns a promise.